# NextJS Error: Failed to collect page data for / when building

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a server component which works when I run in development mode. But when trying to build I get this error `Error: Failed to collect page data for /`

It builds and runs fine when I add the "use client" string at the top but then it doesn't render the components when fetching API data in the `componentDidMount()` state.

```
import {Button, TextField} from "@mui/material";
import React, {RefObject} from "react";
import ChatBubble from "@/app/components/ChatBubble";
import {ChatBubbleModel} from "@/app/models";
import Alert from '@mui/material/Alert';
import AppConfig from "@/app/config";
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
import "./page.css"

interface HomeState {
    buttonDisabled: boolean;
    text: string;
    hasError: boolean;
    errorMessage: string;
    componentArray: React.ReactElement[];
    messages: { role: string; content: string }[];
    preMessagesLoading: boolean
}


export default class Home extends React.Component<{}, HomeState> {
    private scrollableDivRef: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
    private textFieldRef: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            buttonDisabled: false,
            text: '',
            hasError: false,
            errorMessage: '',
            componentArray: [],
            messages: [],
            preMessagesLoading: true
        }
        this.scrollableDivRef = React.createRef()
        this.textFieldRef = React.createRef()
    }

    handleTextChange = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({ text: event.target.value })
    }

    handleKeyDown = (event: any) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            this.handleSend()
        }
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
        this.textFieldFocus()
        try {
            const response: Response = await fetch(AppConfig.apiUrl + '/getAllMessages')
            if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Network issue')
            const data = await response.json()
            const messages = data.messages || []
            this.setState({ messages })
            const messagesArray = this.state.messages
            for (const key in messagesArray) {
                const bubbleChatModel = {
                    message: messagesArray[key].content
                }
                this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    componentArray: [
                        ...prevState.componentArray,
                        <ChatBubble chatBubbleModel={bubbleChatModel} key={bubbleChatModel.message} />
                    ]
                }))
            }
            this.setState({preMessagesLoading: false})
           // @ts-ignore
        } catch (error: Error) {
            console.log('Error fetching previous conversations: ' + error.message)
        } finally {
        }
    }

    textFieldFocus = () => {
        this.textFieldRef.current?.focus()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: {}, prevState: HomeState) {
        if (prevState.componentArray !== this.state.componentArray) {
            this.textFieldFocus();
            if (this.scrollableDivRef.current) {
                this.scrollableDivRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
            }
        }
    }
    handleSend = async () => {
        this.textFieldFocus();
        console.log("sending \"" + this.state.text + "\"");
        this.setState({ buttonDisabled: true });

        const chatBubbleModel = {
            isUser: true,
            username: 'You',
            message: this.state.text,
        };

        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            componentArray: [
                ...prevState.componentArray,
                <ChatBubble chatBubbleModel={chatBubbleModel} key={chatBubbleModel.message} />,
                <Skeleton variant="rounded" height={25} animation="pulse" />,
            ],
            text: '',
        }));
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                AppConfig.apiUrl + "/getMessage",
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ question: this.state.text }),
                }
            );

            if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
            const data = await response.json();
            const systemResponse = data.answer;
            console.log("System Response: " + systemResponse);

            const systemChatBubbleModel = {
                isUser: false,
                username: 'OPVS AI',
                message: systemResponse,
            };

            this.setState((prevState) => {
                const newArray = prevState.componentArray.slice(0, -1);
                return {
                    componentArray: [
                        ...newArray,
                        <ChatBubble chatBubbleModel={systemChatBubbleModel} key={systemChatBubbleModel.message} />,
                    ],
                    buttonDisabled: false,
                };
            });
        //@ts-ignore
        } catch (error: Error) {
            console.error('Error caught: ' + error.message);
            this.setState({
                errorMessage: error.message,
                buttonDisabled: true,
                hasError: true,
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { hasError, errorMessage, text, buttonDisabled, componentArray, preMessagesLoading } = this.state;
        return (
            <main className="flex">
                <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-full h-screen p-5">
                    {hasError ? <Alert severity="error" className="text-red-500">{errorMessage}</Alert> : null}
                    <h1 className="text-3xl font-extrabold text-center pb-4 font-color">Chat Project</h1>
                    { preMessagesLoading ?
                        <Skeleton variant="rectangular" className="w-full h-full" />
                        :<div className="border-4 rounded-xl w-full h-full overflow-y-auto chat-box p-3">
                        {componentArray.map((component, index) => (
                            <div key={index}>
                                {component}
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        <div ref={this.scrollableDivRef}></div>
                    </div>}
                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center pt-5 w-full">
                        <TextField
                            id="outlined-basic"
                            className="w-full"
                            label="Message"
                            variant="outlined"
                            value={text}
                            onChange={this.handleTextChange}
                            onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                            inputRef={this.textFieldRef}
                        />
                        <Button
                            disabled={text === '' ? true : buttonDisabled}
                            className="ml-5 h-full w-1/6"
                            variant="text"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={this.handleSend}
                        >
                            Send Message
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn’t be using react class components nowadays btw

Comment: I guess I should switch to using hooks?